# Show fa icon inside Chtml::link() in Yii1

Tags: yii

Im using `CHtml::link()` for attachment in my grid view and if i click on it, it will open in new tab to display.

My doubt is how can i use font awesome icon to display attachment in grid. Currently it showing from table but i want to display `<i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i>` this icon for that column.

```
array(
    'name'  => 'invoice_attachment',
    'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->invoice_attachment, Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.$data->invoice_attachment, array("target"=>"_blank"))',
    'type'  => 'raw',

  ),
```

The above code is my current output for link.

Comment: replace `<i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i>` with the first parameter of the `CHtml::link` which is `$data->invoice_attachment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CHtml::link($text, $url, $htmlOptions)` method accepts 3 parameters:

1. `$text` - this is what you want, right now youre setting here `$data->invoice_attachment` (propably file name) - change this to your `<i>` string
2. `$url` - a URL or an action route that can be used to create a URL
3. `$htmlOptions` - additional HTML attributes

Change `$text` param and that's all.